# Kerberos Ticket Expiry what happens?

Tags: kerberos

I have noticed a couple of messages about my **Kerberos** credentials expiring.

What does this actually mean and what will happen when they expire?

How do I renew them? Is it just a case of logging in again?

```
-bash-3.00$

        Message from ktkt_warnd@abc.com [ 28 August 2009 01:58:53 BST ] ...

Message to pp@abc.com:

your kerberos credentials expire in less than 30 minutes.

<EOT>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You originally authenticated to the Kerberos *Key Distribution Centre* (KDC) and were given a *ticket-granting ticket* (TGT). You used this TGT to get a ticket for your telnet session (from the KDC): the TGT and this ticket **are separate things**.

The TGT is about to expire. If you want to use it to get any more tickets after this, then you will need to re-authenticate yourself (i.e. obtain a new TGT).

The ticket you currently have for your open telnet session is still valid however, and is unaffected by the TGT expiring.

Comment: Ahh good I was worried that my session containing a long running process would stop working but now you have enlightened me about the TGTs it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: "for your open telnet session"? Does anybody still use telnet?

Comment: @grawity I still use telnet for some testing :-P

Comment: Kerberized telnet uses encryption and so isn't really the same issue as old telnet.